# Smoother collection view scrolling with AVPlayerLayer'd collection view cells

Tags: uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks, avplayer, avplayerlayer

UPDATE: I answered this myself; the code that produces perfectly smooth scrolling in a UICollectionView while playing multiple, simultaneous videos using AVPlayer...

The following code plays up to 10 AVPlayers at a time, each inside a collection view cell. It doesn't crash, and playback is smooth; the only problem, horrible scrolling:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  VideoWall
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 6/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Alan Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";

@interface ViewController () {
    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueueLocal;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)layout
{
    if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout])
    {
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
        dispatchQueueLocal = dispatch_queue_create( "local session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT );
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.height)];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        cell.contentView.layer.sublayers = nil;
        dispatch_release(dispatchQueueLocal);
    }];
    dispatch_retain(dispatchQueueLocal);
    dispatch_async( dispatchQueueLocal, ^{
        [self drawPlayerLayerForCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    });
    [CATransaction commit];

    return cell;
}

- (void)drawPlayerLayerForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    void (^drawPlayerLayer)(UICollectionViewCell*, NSIndexPath*) = ^(UICollectionViewCell* cell, NSIndexPath* indexPath) {
        [AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.imageManager requestPlayerItemForVideo:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] options:nil resultHandler:^(AVPlayerItem * _Nullable playerItem, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if(![[info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] boolValue]) {
                    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]];
                    [playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
                    [playerLayer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
                    [playerLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
                    [playerLayer setFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];

                    [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
                    [(AVPlayer *)playerLayer.player play];

                } else {
                    [AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.imageManager requestImageForAsset:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item]
                                                                          targetSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.flowLayout.itemSize.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.flowLayout.itemSize.height)
                                                                         contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                                                             options:nil
                                                                       resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                               cell.contentView.layer.contents = (__bridge id)result.CGImage;
                                                                           });
                                                                       }];
                }
            });
        }];
    };
    drawPlayerLayer(cell, indexPath);
}

@end
```

Here's the other file (AppDelegate.m -- and, yes, it only takes two files to do this, and there's no XIB/NIB):

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  VideoWall
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 6/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Alan Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch

    self.width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2.0;
    self.height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height / 4.0;

    self.window                    = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [self viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController.view = self.viewController.view;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (ViewController *)viewController {
    ViewController *c = self->_viewController;
    if (!c) {
        c = [[ViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:[self flowLayout]];
        [c.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self->_viewController = c;
    }
    return c;
}

- (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)flowLayout {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *v = self->_flowLayout;
    if (!v) {
        v = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
        [v setItemSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.height)];
        [v setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
        [v setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0];
        [v setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0];
        [v setEstimatedItemSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.height)];
        self->_flowLayout = v;
    }
    return v;
}

- (PHCachingImageManager *)imageManager {
    PHCachingImageManager *i = self->_imageManager;
    if (!i) {
        i = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
        self->_imageManager = i;
    }
    return i;
}

- (PHFetchResult *)assetsFetchResults {
    PHFetchResult *i = self->_assetsFetchResults;
    if (!i) {
        PHFetchResult *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumVideos options:nil];
        PHAssetCollection *collection = smartAlbums.firstObject;
        if (![collection isKindOfClass:[PHAssetCollection class]])
            return nil;
        PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
        allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
        i = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:allPhotosOptions];
        self->_assetsFetchResults = i;
    }
    return i;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

ADDED: Here's a start: NSCache, which I've tried many times with various objects, unsuccessfully; this code caches an entire cell, something I didn't know you could do until I saw it. Works perfectly, but needs advance-lookup; right now, you can scroll back really fast, but forward is the same...

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  VideoWall
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 6/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Alan Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";

@interface ViewController () {
    //dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueueLocal;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)layout
{
    if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout])
    {
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
        //dispatchQueueLocal = dispatch_queue_create( "local session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT );
        self.myCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.height)];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id cell = [self cellForIndexPathItem:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.item]];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueueLocal = [dispatch_queue_create( "local session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT ) autorelease];
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            [[(UICollectionViewCell *)cell contentView].layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
        }];
        dispatch_async( dispatchQueueLocal, ^{
            [self drawPlayerLayerForCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        });
        [CATransaction commit];

        [self performSelector:@selector(setCell:forIndexPathItem:) withObject:cell withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.item]];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)drawPlayerLayerForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    void (^drawPlayerLayer)(UICollectionViewCell*, NSIndexPath*) = ^(UICollectionViewCell* cell, NSIndexPath* indexPath) {
        [AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.imageManager requestPlayerItemForVideo:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] options:nil resultHandler:^(AVPlayerItem * _Nullable playerItem, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if(![[info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] boolValue]) {
                    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]];
                    [playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
                    [playerLayer setBorderColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor];
                    [playerLayer setBorderWidth:0.5f];
                    [playerLayer setFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
                    [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
                    [(AVPlayer *)playerLayer.player play];

                } else {
                    [AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.imageManager requestImageForAsset:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item]
                                                                          targetSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.flowLayout.itemSize.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.flowLayout.itemSize.height)
                                                                         contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                                                             options:nil
                                                                       resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                               cell.contentView.layer.contents = (__bridge id)result.CGImage;
                                                                           });
                                                                       }];
                }
            });
        }];
    };
    drawPlayerLayer(cell, indexPath);
}

- (id)cellForIndexPathItem:(NSNumber *)number {
    return [self.myCache objectForKey:number];
}

- (void)setCell:(id)cell forIndexPathItem:(NSNumber *)number {
    [self.myCache setObject:cell forKey:number];
}

@end
```

--- UPDATE ---

In the UICollectionViewController.m:

```
//
//  CollectionViewController.m
//  ChromaEpsilonZeta
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 6/27/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Alan Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface CollectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib");
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults.count; i++) {
            [self createCellForIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
            NSLog(@"Adding cell %ld out of %ld", i + 1, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults.count);
        }
    });
}

- (CollectionViewCell *)createCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.mappedCells setObject:[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath] forKey:indexPath];

    return (CollectionViewCell *)[AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.mappedCells objectForKey:indexPath];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults.count;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [(CollectionViewCell *)[AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.mappedCells objectForKey:indexPath] setIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.item < 0) indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    NSLog(@"Cell %ld", indexPath.item);

    [(CollectionViewCell *)[AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.mappedCells objectForKey:indexPath] playVideo];

    return (CollectionViewCell *)[AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.mappedCells objectForKey:indexPath];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [(CollectionViewCell *)[AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.mappedCells objectForKey:indexPath] stopVideo];
    [self createCellForIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

In the AppDelegate .m file:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    return YES;
}

- (CollectionViewController *)collectionViewController {
    CollectionViewController *c = self->_collectionViewController;
    if (!c) {
        c = [[CollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:[self flowLayout]];
        [c.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self->_collectionViewController = c;
    }
    return c;
}

- (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)flowLayout {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *v = self->_flowLayout;
    if (!v) {
        v = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        [v setItemSize:CGSizeMake(360.0, 240.0)];
        [v setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
        [v setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0];
        [v setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0];
        [v setEstimatedItemSize:CGSizeMake(227.0, 128.0)];
        [v setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
        self->_flowLayout = v;
    }
    return v;
}

- (PHCachingImageManager *)imageManager {
    PHCachingImageManager *i = self->_imageManager;
    if (!i) {
        i = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
        self->_imageManager = i;
    }
    return i;
}

- (PHFetchResult *)assetsFetchResults {
    PHFetchResult *i = self->_assetsFetchResults;
    if (!i) {
        PHFetchResult *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumVideos options:nil];
        PHAssetCollection *collection = smartAlbums.firstObject;
        if (![collection isKindOfClass:[PHAssetCollection class]])
            return nil;
        PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
        allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
        i = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:allPhotosOptions];
        self->_assetsFetchResults = i;
    }
    return i;
}

- (NSMapTable *)mappedCells {
    NSMapTable *m = self->_mappedCells;
    if (!m) {
        m = [[NSMapTable alloc] initWithKeyOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory valueOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory capacity:self.assetsFetchResults.count];
        self->_mappedCells = m;
        NSLog(@"NSMapTable created");
    }
    NSLog(@"NSMapTable object count: %ld", m.count);
    return m;
}
```

In the UICollectionViewCell subclass (.m) file:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) return nil;

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return self;
}

- (void)playVideo {
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
    self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    [self.playerLayer setFrame:self.contentView.layer.bounds];
    [self.playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    [self.playerLayer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [self.playerLayer setBorderWidth:0.25f];
    [self.contentView.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];
    [(AVPlayer *)self.player play];
    NSLog(@"play");
}

- (void)stopVideo {
    [(AVPlayer *)self.player pause];
    self.contentView.layer.sublayers = nil;
    NSLog(@"stop");
}


- (void)setIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self->_indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.item inSection:0];

        PHVideoRequestOptions *videoOptions = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
        videoOptions.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
        videoOptions.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeFastFormat;
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestPlayerItemForVideo:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[self->_indexPath.item] options:videoOptions resultHandler:^(AVPlayerItem * _Nullable playerItem, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            if(![[info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] boolValue]) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.playerItem = playerItem;
                });
            } else {
                PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
                options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
                options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
                //if (self.contentView.layer.sublayers.count > 0) self.contentView.layer.sublayers = nil;
                [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[self->_indexPath.item]
                                                           targetSize:self.contentView.layer.bounds.size
                                                          contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                                              options:options
                                                        resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                self.contentView.layer.contents = (__bridge id)result.CGImage;
                                                            });
                                                        }];
            }
        }];
}
```

You're welcome.

Comment: Here's my latest iteration of a perfectly smooth-scrolling collection view with real-time video previews (up to 16 at a time:  https://youtu.be/7QlaO7WxjGg  It even uses a cover flow custom layout and "reflection" view that mirrors the video preview perfectly.  The source code is here:  http://www.mediafire.com/download/ivecygnlhqxwynr/VideoWallCollectionView.zip